# Creating a new variable- is there a better way?

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset with around 2 million samples. There are 30 columns for diagnoses which are coded, each labeled I10_DX1 to I10_DX30. I need to create a new variable from these existing columns.

For example, data= CHD_2016,  new variable I would like to generate is =tetralogy. If any of the codes in columns I10_DX1 to I10_DX30 have Q0[01234567], it will be coded 1 otherwise 0. I am able to make it work using the code below. But, I think there has to be a shorter and better way to do it. In stata, I am able to do this in few lines using loop. Can someone suggest a better way please!

````
CHD_2016$tetralogy<- ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX1), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX2), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX3), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX4), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX5), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX6), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX7), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX8), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX9), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX10), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX11), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX12), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX13), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX14), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX15), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX16), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX17), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX18), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX19), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX20), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX21), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX22), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX23), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX24), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX25), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX26), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX27), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX28), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX29), 1, 0)|
          ifelse(grepl("Q0[01234567]", CHD_2016$I10_DX30), 1, 0) ```
````

Comment: Can you provide some example data using `dput(head(df))`?.

Comment: Hi- this is the data like: I10_DX1 = structure(c(4970L, 8006L, 16246L, 16247L, 16246L, 
    7696L), .Label = c("", "A000", "A0100", "A0109", "A011", 
    "A020", "A021", "A0220", "A0221", "A0223", "A0224", "A0225", 
    "A0229", "A028", "A029", "A030", "A031", "A033", "A038", 
    "A039", "A040", "A041", "A042", "A043", "A044", "A045", "A046", 
    "A047", "A048", "A049", "A050", "A051", "A058", "A059", "A060",

Comment: The parenthesis doesn't close. Can you post the data example in the question instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `lapply` with `Reduce` for selected columns

```
cols <- grep('I10_DX', names(CHD_2016))
CHD_2016$tetralogy <- as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(CHD_2016[cols], 
                                 grepl, pattern = "Q0[01234567]")))
```

Also with `sapply` and `rowSums` :

```
CHD_2016$tetralogy <- as.integer(rowSums(sapply(CHD_2016[cols], 
                                 grepl, pattern = "Q0[01234567]")) > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. It looks so neat compared to my code.

Comment: just did. Very impressed by some answers I get on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data variable codes are stored as strings, you can use the `%in%` operator with a `for` loop. Over several million data points though I think solutions involving `lapply` rather than a `for` loop will be much faster.

```
# Example data
ID10_DX1 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
ID10_DX2 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
ID10_DX3 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
ID10_DX4 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
ID10_DX5 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
ID10_DX6 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
ID10_DX7 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
ID10_DX8 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
ID10_DX9 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
ID10_DX10 <- sample(LETTERS)[1:20]
CHD_2016 <- data.frame(ID10_DX1,ID10_DX2,ID10_DX3,ID10_DX4,ID10_DX5,ID10_DX6,ID10_DX7,ID10_DX8,ID10_DX9,ID10_DX10)

# Makes character variables for example data. 
# Not part of the solution and don't use on your own data.
CHD_2016[] <- lapply(CHD_2016, function(x) as.character(x)) 

# This following solution should work to find string "X" in any column
# and report in tetralogy column
string <- "X"
CHD_2016$tetralogy <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(CHD_2016)) { 
  CHD_2016$tetralogy[i] <- string %in% CHD_2016[i,]
}
```